# Why is Checkstyle Not in Maven Central?

Tags: checkstyle

Why is it that I have to download checkstyle to get it to work? Why can I not just pop it in my build file as a dependency?

Comment: You mean like https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to download JAR in order to use `Checkstyle`

For `Maven` you can use: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html or

For `Gradle` you can use: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html

Plugins come with ready `Checkstyle` configurations (based on Google and Sun Microsystems code standards), but you can use custom config file

Here (https://github.com/timurt/checkstyle-samples) you can find my old repository, how to use `Checkstyle` with `Maven` and `Gradle`